# Is it possible to view my comments arranged by score?

Tags: discussion, comments

If there any way to view the list of my comments arranged by their score to find out if some of my comments were popular?

Comment: Probably would need a data.SE query, if the information is in there.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text

Comment: @AlexK. That's great, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its available as a sorted list in the Data Explorer here: [My Most Upvoted Comments (including comment text)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text)